# Is there a permalink for Unikong?

Tags: support, unikong

Clicking the "Play" button in the Unikong ad should give me a unique URL so I can link my friends to it and/or share it on social media. Landing on the URL should immediately spawn a new instance of the Unikong window.

[image]

Comment: Any reason not to just link to your favorite site? Maybe people will come for the game and stay for the thrilling questions. . .

Comment: How is it that the top score board doesn't even have a single "ASS" on it?  This is outrageous!

Comment: @Will You cannot enter initials and it isn't a shared scoreboard :(

Comment: @meagar ultimately, it would be trivially easy for people to abuse javascript to create impossibly high scores with rude initials. We know our user base - if it was a shared scoreboard that would have happened within *about* 6 minutes. We can't invest the necessary time to make it cheat-resistant.

Comment: If it was a shared scoreboard, knowing the tech savvy community here, there would be a lot of ASS 999999e99 posted within the first hour. Edit: Marc beat me to it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes we can. It is pretty obvious in source or just by opening frame in new tab with any extensions that adds such menu item: https://stackoverflow.com/seriously/unikong

Comment: Will this link stay active after April Fool's?

Comment: I don't know, but considering it is pure JS game you can just save it and all resources and play it whenever you want.

Comment: It's an empty page now. Rest well, sweet prince.

Comment: I didn't get the chance to play it :/

Comment: since this is gone is it still possible to get the js? i really liked it.